# Is there an alternative to Adobe Flash?

Tags: firefox, flash, adobe, gnash

I am having problems with Adobe Flash. I have the latest version installed for Firefox. It keeps crashing my computer and I was wondering if there was any alternative that works with
videos that require an updated Flash. If there isn't an alternative, is there any software that keeps flash stable? Another problem I have is that even though I updated my Flash, some videos say that my Flash isn't updated.
I know Flash is pretty rubbish in Linux and OSX. Is there any alternative for Flash? Is [Gnash](http://gnashdev.org/) any good? Is it still supported and developed? Please help.

Comment: What Ubuntu are you running? 32 or 64 bit? How does flash run on Chrome or Chromium?

Comment: I am using 32bit 12.04 I will try chrome but am looking for a way to fix Firefox rather than to switch browser will let you know about chrome tho.....

Comment: Try Gnash or Lightspark then

Comment: if by alternative you mean a good or better one, the answer is 'no'. I just tried Gnash and Lightspark and I  will agree with the respondent Bowser, below :http://askubuntu.com/a/163486/47206

Comment: someone should make an answer on shumway

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For alternatives as you said, there's Gnash and [Lightspark](http://lightspark.github.com/).

To install open Terminal (Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and copy the following commands in the Terminal:

For "[Official PPA of the Lightspark project](https://launchpad.net/~sparkers/+archive/ppa)"[image: Launchpad logo]:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sparkers/ppa
```

or for "[Automated daily builds from ustream git master](https://launchpad.net/~sparkers/+archive/daily)"[image: Launchpad logo]:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sparkers/daily
```

Installation:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lightspark browser-plugin-lightspark
```

[Click here for instructions on using PPAs.](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983)

*NOTE* - Update for Ubuntu 15.04, using Lightspark Version 0.7.2-6 (The above PPA repository does not appear to be working in Ubuntu 15.04)

Lightspark 0.7.2-6 deb package can be installed directly via the software centre, which is invoked by clicking the "Install Using Apt" button on the following web page:

http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/vivid/universe/base/browser-plugin-lightspark

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you use Flash for. If you only need it for Youtube and a few well known sites you can use the addon FlashVideoReplacer for Firefox, or the Greasemonkey script [Linterna Mágica](http://linterna-magica.nongnu.org/). LM works on many sites and also on Chrome and Opera in additional to Firefox, though I notice that if Flash is installed it doesn't work on Firefox (Flash player will load while LM is loading, so you have two instances of the video). Also LM doesn't work on Youtube if you use Chrome (it used to, it just stopped working a few days ago)

For Youtube you also have other options like [Minitube](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/minitube/) or [SMPlayer](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/smplayer/) (install from [rvm's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~rvm/+archive/ppa), the new versions have a Youtube viewer)

I have played with Gnash and Lightspark on different distros and different machines. My conclusion is that they are complete waste of time. They never work except for a few demos. I see people recommending them on many Linux sites, either they have better experience somehow or these guys have never tried it themselves.

Comment: My setup is the following. If I have flash installed and use firefox then I use flashvideoreplacer on the supported sites.

If I have not installed flash and use Firefox I use LinternaMagica.

Comment: FlashVideoReplacer: [_This add-on has been removed by its author._](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashvideoreplacer/)

Answer (score 0):

Although Gnash is preffered, you also have Lightspark.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sssup/sssup-ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install lightspark
```

Note: Lightspark requires Adobe Flash removed before installation.

Better still, use Google Chrome. It has Flash built in (though Chromium does not).

Comment: I would like to continue using Firefox as I just dont like the look of ubuntu chrome all text is tiny at 1080p

Comment: Why do you say `gnash` is preferable to `lightspark`?

Comment: Because me and my friends have never had problems with it. :P

Comment: This PPA [ppa:sssup/sssup-ppa](https://launchpad.net/~sssup/+archive/sssup-ppa) is only for Maverick and Natty which both don't supported anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the flash plugin from the software center or through the terminal using `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer`

Answer (score -1):

One that I tried recently is **swfdec**. It is very good! It can be downloaded from

```
sudo apt-get install swfdec-gnome
```

It can also be found on the ubuntu software center.

Comment: [Unmaintained since 2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swfdec). `apt-cache show swfdec-gnome` shows: "_This package is a transitional package for upgrading to Gnash. It can be safely removed when Gnash is installed._"