# Alternative to Flash Player for Firefox

Tags: firefox, flash

I want to find an alternative to Flash for Mozilla Firefox. In Chromium I am using Pepper Flash which is great so I want to know if there is something similar for Firefox. I have found a lot of similar questions like [[1]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163439/is-there-an-alternative-to-adobe-flash)[[2]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/444166/flash-player-alternative-for-firefox) but most of them are outdated and the latest one proposes to stick to Flash.  Until now I have come across Lightspark. It is any good? What is the best choice?

Comment: Haven't personally tried this: http://www.webupd8.org/2015/01/fresh-player-plugin-sees-new-release.html

Comment: Have you tried Adobe flash player?

Comment: @fahim That is the one I want to replace as you can see in my post!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pepper Flash in Firefox too. For doing that, Start terminal and type following commands on terminal :

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install freshplayerplugin
```